# Ionic framework don't save token

Tags: android, ionic-framework, devicetoken

I have a problem with [Ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/). I follow the guide to receive and send push notification, but something doesn't work.

When I launch the app, I press button Identify, and show my an alert that say the user ID. After, I press on register button, the phone show me an alert that contains the Device token(ANDROID). But when I go to ionic.io, in the dashboard of my app, the device token there isn't.

If I don't have the token saved on my dashboard, I can't send push notification.
Anyone can help me?

This is my controller.js:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicUser, $ionicPush) {

 // Identifies a user with the Ionic User service
  $scope.identifyUser = function() {
    console.log('Ionic User: Identifying with Ionic User service');

    var user = $ionicUser.get();
    if(!user.user_id) {
      // Set your user_id here, or generate a random one.
      user.user_id = $ionicUser.generateGUID();
    };

    // Add some metadata to your user object.
    angular.extend(user, {
      name: 'Ionitron',
      bio: 'I come from planet Ion'
    });

    // Identify your user with the Ionic User Service
    $ionicUser.identify(user).then(function(){
      $scope.identified = true;
      alert('Identified user ' + user.name + '\n ID ' + user.user_id);
    });
  };  

  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:tokenReceived', function(event, data) {
  console.log('Got token', data.token, data.platform);
  // Do something with the token
});

    // Registers a device for push notifications and stores its token
  $scope.pushRegister = function() {

    console.log('Ionic Push: Registering user');

    // Register with the Ionic Push service.  All parameters are optional.
    $ionicPush.register({
      canShowAlert: true, //Can pushes show an alert on your screen?
      canSetBadge: true, //Can pushes update app icon badges?
      canPlaySound: true, //Can notifications play a sound?
      canRunActionsOnWake: true, //Can run actions outside the app,
      onNotification: function(notification) {
        // Handle new push notifications here
        // console.log(notification);
        return true;
      }
    });
  };

  // Handles incoming device tokens
  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:tokenReceived', function(event, data) {
    alert("Successfully registered token " + data.token);
    console.log('Ionic Push: Got token ', data.token, data.platform);
    $scope.token = data.token;
  });

})



.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {
  // With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called
  // when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.
  // To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),
  // listen for the $ionicView.enter event:
  //
  //$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
  //});

  $scope.chats = Chats.all();
  $scope.remove = function(chat) {
    Chats.remove(chat);
  };
})

.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats) {
  $scope.chat = Chats.get($stateParams.chatId);
})

.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    enableFriends: true
  };
});
```

I follow the ionic guide step-by-step

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem..

Comment: I resolve the problem using PARSE

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the token on ionic.io , you have to push it through:

```
var push = new Ionic.Push();
var user = Ionic.User.current();

var callback = function(pushToken) {
  console.log('Registered token:', pushToken.token);
  user.addPushToken(pushToken);
  user.save(); // you NEED to call a save after you add the token
}

push.register(callback);
```

as mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-usage).